# spring boot traking updated values

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I've been searching if there is a method or function on spring boot, jpa, hibernate to know which values will be updated before saving/updating an element in the database, but still haven't found anything, does something like that exist or do I need to create my own method for that?

For example:
Original object:
Name = John
Last_Name = Jhons

New object:
Name = John
Last_Name = Stevens

Change: Last_Name from Jhons to Stevens

I have an idea to do that on Java, but the clients wants to avoid all the unnecesary coding.

Answer (score 0):

With `Hibernate` you can implement `PreUpdateEvent` callback:

```
public class PreUpdateEventListenerImpl implements PreUpdateEventListener
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event)  {
        Object newEntity=event.getEntity(); 
        Object[] newState = event.getNewState(); // New entity properties
        Object[] oldState = event.getOldState(); // Old entity properties
    }
}
```